I am trying to launch my Pi camera, but keep failing every time
I am using ubuntu linux 22.04(LTS) Jammy version.. I tried may times to accesss my raspberry pi camera module(V2 model) in raspberry pi 4 via ssh.. I installed all packages based on Libcamera (like libcamera-dev,libcamera-apps,etc..) but I facing Issues while configuring the camera in this os there are only one options based on camera in Interfacing options which is Legacy camera but Libcamera doesn't support Legacy camera.. what is the solution??

Please try Raspberry Pi OS. All the hardware is supported out of the box there

@ArchismanPanigrahi, The camera is an add on module  No Pi board that I know comes with a webcam out of the box,

Please provide how you built or where you bought this camera.  In the meatime I'm flagging the post to be moved to the Pi stack exchange

Still, thr official camera module will be fully supported out of the box in Raspberry Pi OS
